# Is it okay two import same .scss file to two different .scss file?

Tags: css, import, sass

Does it cache one file or it will me imported twice and double my code?

lets says I have `variable.scss` and have to import it into those two `apple.scss` | `orange.scss`. Is this alright thing to do?

Comment: It depends on your usage.

Comment: @SauravRastogi what do you mean? I just want to import those variables and use them in those two files

Comment: If your `variable.scss` only contains `$scss-variables`, then they will disappear after compilation; so no duplication. If the file you're importing contains anything else, other than a `%placeholder`, then you'll get duplication.

Comment: @Ari Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for :3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to import a `variable.scss` file as much times as necessary, but only if there is no styling in it, if you have other css selectors and styling applied to that file, then you will be getting duplication.